# Paraview/ParaVis crashes when I use Delanuay 2D filter

Tags: paraview

I need to make a contour plot in ParaView using the data in a .CSV file (below shows the contents of the CSV file).

1. I opened the .CSV file.
2. I converted the table to points using Apply Filters > Alphabetical > Table to points. It correctly shows the points.

However, when I try to make a surface using Apply Filters > Alphabetical > Delaunay 2D, Paraview crashes without any warning or error message.

I appreciate your help.

CSV file contents:

X,Y,Z,r,t,SF,S3
12.7926075059,0.0,126.915788562,0.12517074897,42.2814100463,1.60482807934,-0.687400369352
12.7807760239,0.0,126.925498962,0.10988708129,42.6858481071,1.62795037289,-0.706761293847
12.7779463589,0.0,126.922053641,0.110232797835,45.0,1.6464130146,-0.807434089668
12.7884426871,0.0,126.911557313,0.125076847565,45.0,1.61978019578,-0.807434089668
12.7881135941,0.0,126.934440613,0.109827313125,36.6504500699,1.59339243868,-0.367532641059
12.795798626,0.0,126.919787304,0.12494580136,39.9396160985,1.57828780856,-0.564739362532
12.8008715206,0.0,126.925916415,0.125153670452,36.2948665903,1.57016039847,-0.345515190974
12.7935657501,0.0,126.944641113,0.108715941493,30.611003424,1.55757884643,-0.0665950131761
12.8037909994,0.0,126.930303743,0.12502055777,33.8815893697,1.53919333052,-0.203253512942
12.8080240128,0.0,126.93691294,0.12509662047,30.2853382092,1.53006317614,-0.0582195231874
12.7990179062,0.0,126.954841614,0.1088293416,24.5159658011,1.56192276874,-0.0441760208926
12.8104699534,0.0,126.941790798,0.124867617311,27.785795173,1.51027941936,-0.0244667710719
12.8140480505,0.0,126.948615387,0.125089313141,24.2540560722,1.52810128045,-0.0478930987296
12.8023748398,0.0,126.965911865,0.107900920999,18.416404707,1.57477273186,-0.158468250131
12.8161004711,0.0,126.953786391,0.124960061905,21.7049505837,1.50618998465,-0.0917536271114
12.8187903691,0.0,126.96093061,0.125050265851,18.2057034119,1.52531853013,-0.162784139255
12.8057327271,0.0,126.976982117,0.108209207193,12.2815934839,1.61803968282,-0.272388322073
12.8202233787,0.0,126.966436258,0.124820613706,15.598572851,1.51275655565,-0.214458804166
12.8222548688,0.0,126.97369559,0.125052688618,12.1426657343,1.55114162935,-0.274577716836
12.8068666458,0.0,126.988487244,0.10748499219,6.14876717685,1.6549597612,-0.346653085286
12.8232091326,0.0,126.979347385,0.124928062786,9.51559551549,1.54254874397,-0.3116687398
12.8243260603,0.0,126.986766246,0.125028402904,6.07590948472,1.57077865835,-0.347261042894
12.8245787653,0.0,126.992554673,0.124801048306,3.42015752191,1.56851331839,-0.364216439803
12.7446593025,0.0,126.955665301,0.062928680533,44.7910158798,1.79685284461,-0.798956662559
12.7445119036,0.0,126.955488096,0.0629493378151,45.0,1.79913872397,-0.807434089668
12.7457738919,0.0,126.954226108,0.0647340587094,45.0,1.79327790988,-0.807434089668
12.7492587198,0.0,126.960966971,0.0628490163825,38.3936050984,1.69677036832,-0.474606105815
12.7489875751,0.0,126.960582629,0.0628769562898,38.8215527813,1.7024877583,-0.50014334819
12.7531519099,0.0,126.966944489,0.0625922707632,31.8777438805,1.67662180663,-0.108874760866
12.7528671735,0.0,126.966395155,0.0626436243366,32.4419461665,1.68227922358,-0.132224693099
12.7565175926,0.0,126.973157075,0.0625682101357,25.4052935699,1.56398283511,-0.0336910025443
12.7562635618,0.0,126.972552571,0.0626015155488,26.0048175566,1.56940069195,-0.0283604652866
12.7590267344,0.0,126.979867181,0.0623657418635,18.8334649555,1.57692830038,-0.149890468225
12.758829443,0.0,126.979125616,0.0624230987684,19.5361533097,1.58039914099,-0.135423708125
12.7609607308,0.0,126.986671725,0.0624007500722,12.3329113973,1.4711606657,-0.271579591123
12.7608238233,0.0,126.985915239,0.0624333081332,13.0379803636,1.4732542024,-0.260170564099
12.7619427115,0.0,126.993759434,0.0622562782225,5.75298796042,1.54463322833,-0.349804911445
12.7619086643,0.0,126.992918812,0.0623123257072,6.52520241272,1.54568832102,-0.343494478353
12.7645875521,0.0,126.935412448,0.0913405921616,45.0,1.67716785868,-0.807434089668
12.8250408362,0.0,127.0,0.125040836166,0.0,1.5918599592,-0.372134789536
12.8079996109,0.0,127.0,0.107999610901,0.0,1.68307666667,-0.372134789536
12.8079996109,0.0,127.0,0.107999610901,0.0,1.68307666667,-0.372134789536
12.7623769659,0.0,127.0,0.0623769659179,0.0,1.44840455139,-0.372134789536

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get your data to work by transforming the points by 90 degrees about the x-axis, then applying the Delaunay2D filter. To do so, load the points like you have, apply the Table to Points filter, then apply a Transform filter with the first text box of the "Rotate" setting to 90. Finally, apply the Delaunay2D filter. It should work without crashing.

[image]

If you want to get the points back to the original coordinate space, Transform the results of the Delaunay2D filter by -90 degrees about the x-axis.

The likely cause of the crash is that the default setting is to project the points to the XY plane. When you do this with your data, the projected points are colinear, so Delaunay triangulation does not work. I did not bet better results with the Best-Fitting Plane setting.

Comment: Thanks Cory. I had actually used the Best-Fitting Plane setting and it was causing a crash too. The other way that I found working for these data was using 2D Points option and using X data for X column and Z data for Y column. However, the problem is that these remedies are not general and you don't know whether they would work for other data sets. I wish I could realize what the cause of the crash is so that I can prevent generation of problematic data it in my code.

Comment: I think it is a deficiency in the Delaunay 2D filter code. The Best-Fitting Plane method failed for me as well. As I recall, the plane fitting code is not robust enough to handle points aligned with certain planes, which may be how your data is arranged.